# 2D Water in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I've programmed a 2D Water Effect with Springs similar to [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44547/how-do-i-create-2d-water-with-dynamic-waves) one. Now I want to implement it in a Vertex Shader (in Unity). But for Wave Propagation I need to know the left and right Neighbors (to calculate the affecting Force) of the current Vertex and somehow save the resulting Force for the next Iteration. I have no Idea how to do that.

Comment: you can't find neighbours in shader.see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfX9dzhBhg0) I hope It will help you

Comment: Thaks for the Advise, I watched the Tutorial.
I've already known this approach to simulate Water and Ripple Effects. (I already programmed such Water shader)

But I wanted to Implement these Water Effects with the Spring Approach. Since its not possible to acces other Vertices in Shader, are there other possible Solution to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a texture representation of the offsets you need for vertex manipulation and then use tex2lod() in your vertex shader - these are supported in shader model 3 and up.

You then use a fragment shader to generate or update the texture.

Your vertex shader could look something like this:

```
sampler2D _OffsetMap;

// vertex shader
vert_data vert (appdata_base v) {
     vert_data v_out;
     float4 vertexPos = v.vertex;
     vertexPos += tex2Dlod (_OffsetMap, float4(vertexPos.xz, 0, 0));
     v_out.position = UnityObjectToClipPos (vertexPos);
     return v_out;
}
```

You can ofcourse also use the same fetch to manipulate vertex normals.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, I will look into that. But how can I store the new Vertex Positions, so that on the next Time the Shader is called, I can access the updated Vertex Positions?

Comment: As I wrote above, you will have to use a multi-pass setup where a fragment shader renders the offset texture/displacement map for each frame of animation, and then you pass this texture on to the vertex shader above. This is sometimes called Dynamic Displacement Mapping. You should be able to find plenty of examples on the web.